# Error: Cannot find module 'binary-extensions'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am trying to use reactjs on local system.
I followed the official documentation of reactjs and was trying its tutorial on tic tac toe.

For local development environment I followed all the steps but when I try to run `npm start` I am getting below error

```
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'binary-extensions'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/Documents/my- 
app/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/is-binary-path/index.js:3:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

I am using `Node v8.11.3` and `npm v5.6.0`

FYI I have installed `binary-extensions` using `npm i binary-extensions` but I am still getting same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow, your project has lost track of the `binary-extensions` module.

The fix is simple.

In your project, delete `node_modules/` and `package-lock.json`.

macOS / Linux:

```
rm -rf node_modules/
rm package-lock.json
```

Windows:

```
rmdir node_modules/
rm package-lock.json
```

Then,

```
npm install
```

This will resolve the issue.

Comment: You might want to remove the package-lock.json file also.

Comment: this answer was written before package-lock.json existed, but yes, that should be deleted too